# Finding characters with minimum frequency

Tags: python

As the title says, I am trying to print  ALL characters with the minimum frequency:
least_occurring is holding only ONE value so I think that is the issue but can't figure it out..it could be something obvious I am missing here but I am out of brain cells :)

```
 ex:  aabbccdddeeeffff

expected output:

Least occuring character :  a,b,c  <=== this is what I can't figure out :( 
repeated 2 time(s)

--------------------------
Character   Frequency
--------------------------
a                2
b                2
c                2
d                3
e                3
f                4
```

results I am getting:

```
Least occurring character is:  a
It is repeated 2 time(s)

--------------------------
Character   Frequency
--------------------------
 a                  2
 b                  2
 c                  2
 d                  3
 e                  3
 f                  4
```

my code:

```
# Get string from user
string = input("Enter some text: ")

# Set frequency as empty dictionary
frequency_dict = {}
tab="\t\t\t\t\t"
for character in string:
    if character in frequency_dict:
        frequency_dict[character] += 1
    else:
        frequency_dict[character] = 1

least_occurring = min(frequency_dict, key=frequency_dict.get)

# Displaying result
print("\nLeast occuring character is: ", least_occurring)
print("Repeated %d time(s)" %(frequency_dict[least_occurring]))
# Displaying result
print("\n--------------------------")
print("Character\tFrequency")
print("--------------------------")
for character, frequency in frequency_dict.items():
    print(f"{character + tab + str(frequency)}")
```

Comment: Take a look at the Counter class in the *collections* module

Comment: `min` only returns one value.

Comment: No need to re-invent the wheel. Here is the good explanation of Counter tool mentioned here in comments: https://realpython.com/python-counter/

Comment: @CrazyChucky, yes.. I am aware of that .. need to find a way to fix that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Counter class from the *collections* module is ideal for this. However, in this trivial case, just use a dictionary.

```
s = 'aabbccdddeeeffff'

counter = {}
# count the occurrences of the individual characters
for c in s:
    counter[c] = counter.get(c, 0) + 1
# find the lowest value 
min_ = min(counter.values())
# create a list of all characters where the count matches the previously calculated minimum 
lmin = [k for k, v in counter.items() if v == min_]
# print the results
print('Least occuring character : ', end='')
print(*lmin, sep=', ')
```

**Output:**

```
Least occuring character : a, b, c
```

Comment: Thanks @Stuart, just finished reading about Counters--it handles situation like this better  I think

Comment: Can you elaborate on "counter[c] = counter.get(c, 0) + 1" ?  this is get function from dictionary right ? and we setting it to 0?

Comment: `get` second parameter is what it should return in case key (here `c`) is not in dictionary

Comment: got it -- so counter['d'] in this example is 3 -- and it's in loop to iterate all char in the string .

Answer (score 1):

You are very close!

If you have `min` value why not just iterate over your dictionary and check all keys that values are the `min` one?

```
for k, v in frequency_dict.items():
    if v == least_occurring:
        print(k)
```

Comment: it's screaming at my face but I just couldn't figure it out -- but seems that counter make this kind of scenarios much easier. I am new to python/programming but it's interesting to learn different approaches.. thank you !!